# When clicking on an anchor tag, how to save that elements ID so I can use it later?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a bunch of listings on my website like this:

```
<a class="listing" id=""></a>
<a class="listing" id=""></a>
<a class="listing" id=""></a>
```

Each having unique data and ID's loaded from my database.
When I click on one of hem, it opens a panel that has information about it. I dont want to display all information, just parts. On the other panel, I have a button:

```
<div class="info-panel>
  <button class="load-other-info"></button>
</div>
```

I want to load some of the data initially, which is easy with an onclick=function(). But how can I store the onclick ID attribute so if I click on the panel button it knows to load the data specific to the listings ID that I clicked previous?
I am thinking I need to store it as some variable, then when the button is clicked do an AJAX request with that variable to my PHP file to query the rest of the data row columns based on that ID. 
I am new to javascript so I dont really understand how to store variables like other languages. thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). We probably need to know more about how you create/use the panel you're passing the data to in order to help you in any but the most vague way.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
let listings = [];
$(function() { // when page loads
  $(".listing").on("click",function() {
    listings.push(this.id); // save each ID clicked
    $(this).addClass("clicked"); // show it is chosen
  });
  $("load-other-info").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // or use type=button on the button
    $.get("info.php",{data:JSON.stringify(listings)},function(data){
      $("#someInfoContainer").html(data);
    })
  }); 
})
```